# Does curl need some special parameters to enforce charset/encoding?

Tags: web-services, curl, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm using a curl command to send a large file (100+ MB) to a web service. I'm noticing that only when I send the file to the web service using curl the file gets mangled and data is lost.

Here is the command I'm using to send the file:

```
curl -v --raw -X POST  -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8" -d @medline16n0736.xml "http://localhost:2323/TestWebService"
```

Am I missing something? I thought telling it to use `text/xml` and `charset=UTF-8` would keep it UTF-8 once received by the web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking curl to post the XML file using the `-d` option, which will post the file as if it were being submitted via an HTTP webform in `application/x-www-webform-urlencoded` format.  To post the file by itself, use the `-T` option instead.  Also, you are using the `--raw` option, which will disable handling of HTTP transfer encodings, even though you are sending a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header.  Remove `--raw` and `-T` will detect the header to enable chunking.

You are also asking curl to send a `Content-Type` header to tell the WebService that the uploaded data is UTF-8 encoded XML.  It is your responsibility to make sure the XML file is *actually* UTF-8 encoded.  Curl won't check that for you.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.